# If statement not being executed as intended

Tags: c#

I'm having some problems to  trigger the if statement , i have 5 options the last one is an else and every thing but the numbers  1,2,3,4 should trigger the else but even those number are trigging it.

the code :

```
char choice = (char)Console.Read();

// choosing an option
if (choice == 1) // if user input == 1
{
    Console.WriteLine("Insert World's name: ");
}
else if (choice == 2) //if user input == 2
{
    Console.WriteLine("Loading World");
}
else if (choice == 3) //if user input == 3
{
    Console.WriteLine("Audio");
    Console.WriteLine("Graphics");
    Console.WriteLine("Controller");
    Console.WriteLine("Tutorial");
}
else if (choice == 4) //if user input == 4
{
    Console.WriteLine("You sure ?");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Choose a valid option"); // if any option of above is not trigged then do this
}
```

Comment: Hint: `1` is not the same as `'1'`

Comment: Hint: '1' = 0x31 = 49

Comment: I think you'll find [this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) about character encoding pretty insightful.

Comment: Hint format the question left

Comment: Therefore, change your if statements like -- if ( choice == '1' )

Comment: Thank you guys , i was thinking the same way but with different syntax , i was trying to put the Console.read() in the if statement but it wasn't allowing me , well thank you

Comment: `char choice = (char)Console.Read();` change that to be `int` and you wont have to wrap your conditional check around `' '` also read up on the difference between `char && string && int`

Comment: change it to `var choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the commenters have already pointed out, numeric characters are not numbers, `1 != '1'`.  I won't follow that one up, I figure you already got that message.

Since this is designed to interact with a user it might be clearer and more useful to use the `Console.ReadKey` method to acquire keypresses.  The return value is a structure that contains a lot more information about the key that was pressed, including the modifier keys and so on.  Instead of doing comparisons with characters there is an enum that names each key.

This is how I'd approach your problem:

```
string worldName = string.Empty;

// wait for keypress, don't display it to the user
// If you want to display it, remove the 'true' parameter
var input = Console.ReadKey(true);

// test the result
if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.D1 || input.Key == ConsoleKey.NumPad1)
{
    Console.Write("Insert World's name: ");
    worldName = Console.ReadLine();
}
else if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.D2 || input.Key == ConsoleKey.NumPad2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Loading World: {0}", worldName);
}
```

And so on.

What it also allows you to do, which the `Console.Read` method does not, is to handle keypresses that are not alphanumeric.  For example, if you want to use function keys instead:

```
// F1
if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.F1)
{
    Console.Write("Insert World's name: ");
    worldName = Console.ReadLine();
}
// F2
else if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.F2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Loading World: {0}", worldName);
}
```

And of course handling keyboard modifiers:

```
// Shift-F1
if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.F1 && input.Modifiers == ConsoleModifiers.Shift)
{
    Console.Write("Insert World's name: ");
    worldName = Console.ReadLine();
}
// F2 with any comnination of modifiers that does not include Alt
// (F2, Shift-F2, Ctrl-F2, Ctrl-Shift-F2)
else if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.F2 && !input.Modifiers.HasFlag(ConsoleModifiers.Alt))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Loading World: {0}", worldName);
}
```